# Trying to dynamically create number of fields in a form - A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, because I have multiple forms on multiple pages, I thought it'd be better to have some components which dynamically create the number of rows needed in a form.

I have just tried this approach:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-eynfaa

but I get

```
A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen.
```

and if I console.log the formValues on submit I don't get the desired output.

So, is there something wrong with my approach? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You get the `controlled to uncontrolled` warning when the initial value of your input is `undefined` and on the second render its value is something other than `undefined`. In your case I think you want your input to be controlled, hence you have to always provide a value not equal to `undefined`, like an empty string or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `setFormValues` in `updateValue` function of `CreateRow` component is overriding `formValues` state object (note that `setState` from hooks and set state of React class components work differently - [see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)), effectively removing all values apart from the one currently set. You can simply fix this by spreading the current `formValues` object like so:

```
setFormValues({ ...formValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```